# Can I use an Arel created alias as part of includes rather than join for eager fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, alias

I have a self referencing relationship where an Employee will reference the same table as it's Supervisor. I need to query the table and be able to sort by "supervisor.first_name" which is technically, "employees.first_name". I was able to create a join using Arel however, I need it eager fetched so that I can use that alias in the `order` clause.

```
immediate_supervisor_alias = Employee.arel_table.alias(:supervisor)
  supervisor_join = immediate_supervisor_alias.create_on(
      Employee.arel_table[:id].eq(immediate_supervisor_alias[:id])
)
```

And then I use that like so...

```
@employees = Employee.joins(
          Employee.arel_table.create_join(
              immediate_supervisor_alias, supervisor_join, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
          )
      )
      .includes(...)
      .order('supervisor.first_name ASC')
```

This works, but fails to sort because the supervisor is lazy loaded. I need it to be an `includes` but I can't find anything about how to use an alias there. Arel API docs haven't been much help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it to work. I don't know if this is the best way, but it does work, so calling it good unless someone comes by with a better answer.

```
@employees = Employee.joins(
          Employee.arel_table.create_join(
              immediate_supervisor_alias, supervisor_join, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
          )
      )
      .select('supervisor.id, supervisor.last_name, supervisor.first_name')
      .includes(...)
      .order('supervisor.first_name ASC')
```

Note the addition of the `select`.